# How to send only file name instead of file path in post request

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am using IE9 and jquery1.8. I am making a POST request using ajaxForm. The form contains one file input field only. It sends the POST request as below,

```
-----------------------------7dd2d50120f76
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="myFile"; filename="C:\Images\myfile.jpg"
Content-Type: text/plain
```

As in the log the filename contains filepath. I am trying to pass **only filename** and not the path. Is there any way I can achieve this?

**EDIT:**
I checked on IE 8 and it is sending only filename instead of filepath. This file path is breaking the server code which is expecting only filename. Wondering there should be some attribute or something which need to be set OR IE9 has some changes related to this.

Thanks,
Jdp

Comment: Why do you need this client side? It should be easy to take care of on the server

Answer (score 1):

In IE it's a security feature, if site is not in trusted zone. In other browsers, if you absolutely must do this on client (I still think parsing the name on the server is a much better option) - you have to save the "name only" into separate hidden field and then read that field on the server:

```
<form onsubmit = "getFileName()">
    <input type="file" id="fu"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="hdFileName" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>

<script>
    function getFileName() {
        var hid = document.getElementById("hdFileName");
        var fullName = document.getElementById("fu").value;

        var sep = fullName.lastIndexOf("\\"); 
        if (sep == -1)
            hid.value = fullName;
        else
            hid.value = fullName.substring(sep + 1, fullName.length);

        // Testing
        alert(hid.value);

    }
</script>
```

This code fires on form submit and checks if filename contains "\" character. If it does - it reads filename only part (if it doesn't - it already filename only) and stores it into a hidden variable.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wKvGP/